# React Native - Modal with Flatlist items

Tags: javascript, android, react-native, modal-dialog

I'm making a modal that will popup when the user clicks a flatlist button or items, and there the user will see the details about the item he/she clicks. Basically, I want to pass the items of flatlist to modal.

I'm actually done with the popup of the modal, now I have to show the details like menu description and menu price. I've found a post here in stackoverflow and I follow everything in there but I am having an error regarding with an " id ", and I can't figure out how to fix it.

Here is my code

Details.js

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import {Text, TouchableHighlight, View,
StyleSheet, Platform, FlatList, AppRegistry,
TouchableOpacity, RefreshControl, Dimensions, Modal, TextInput, TouchableWithoutFeedback, Keyboard
} from 'react-native';

import AddModal from '../Modal/AddModal';

var screen = Dimensions.get('window');

const DismissKeyboard = ({ children }) => (
    <TouchableWithoutFeedback onPress = {() => Keyboard.dismiss()}>
        {children}
    </TouchableWithoutFeedback>
);

export default class Details extends Component {
    static navigationOptions = {
        title: ''
    };
    constructor()
    {
        super ()
        this.state = {
            data: [],
            showModal: false,
            id: null,
        }
    }

    fetchData = async() => {
        const { params } = this.props.navigation.state;
        const response_Cat = await fetch('http://192.168.254.101:3307/categories/' + params.id);
        const category_Cat = await response_Cat.json();
        this.setState({data: category_Cat});
    };

    componentDidMount() {
        this.fetchData();
    };

    _onRefresh() {
        this.setState({ refreshing: true });
        this.fetchData().then(() => {
            this.setState({ refreshing: false })
        });
    };

    _onPressItem(id) {
        this.setState({
            modalVisible: true,
            id: id
        });
    }

    _renderItem = ({item}) => {
        return (
            <TouchableHighlight
                id = { item.menu_desc }
                onPress = { this._onPressItem(item.menu_desc) }
            >
                <View>
                    <Text>{ this.state.id }</Text>
                </View>
            </TouchableHighlight>
        )
    };

  render() {
    const { params } = this.props.navigation.state;
      return (
          <View style = { styles.container }>
            <AddModal
                modalVisible = { this.state.modalVisible }
                setModalVisible = { (vis) => { this.setModalVisible(vis) }}
                id = { this.state.id }
            />
              <FlatList
                data = { this.state.data }
                renderItem = { this._renderItem }
                keyExtractor={(item, index) => index}
                /*refreshControl = {
                    <RefreshControl
                        refreshing = { this.state.refreshing }
                        onRefresh = { this._onRefresh.bind(this) }
                    />
                }*/
              />
          </View>
      );
  }

}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
...
})

//AppRegistry.registerComponent('Details', () => Details);
```

AddModal.js

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import {Text, TouchableHighlight, View,
StyleSheet, Platform, FlatList, AppRegistry,
TouchableOpacity, RefreshControl, Dimensions, TextInput, Modal
} from 'react-native';

export default class AddModal extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            showModal: false,
            id: null
        };
    }

    componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps) {
        this.setState({
            showModal: nextProps.showModal,
            id: nextProps.id,
        })
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <Modal
                animationType="slide"
                transparent={ true }
                visible={ this.state.modalVisible }
                onRequestClose={() => { this.props.setModalVisible(false) }}>
                    <View>
                        <View>
                            <Text>{ this.state.id }</Text>
                            <TouchableHighlight
                                onPress = {() => { this.props.setModalVisible(false) }}
                            >
                                <Text>Hide Modal</Text>
                            </TouchableHighlight>
                        </View>
                    </View>
            </Modal>
        )
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just wanted to pointout an issue in your code (not related to 'id' error, id error already answer by `digit`). In the `renderItem` function, you are calling `onPress = { this._onPressItem(item.menu_desc) }`, it should be changed to

```
onPress = { () => this._onPressItem(item.menu_desc) }
```

I guess, you will call the `onPressItem` when user click on list item.

**EDIT:**

I have made a couple of changes to make your code working. Here are the changes.

In your `AppModal.js`, you are setting modal visibility in `showModal: nextProps.showModal` , but in the `<Modal ...>` you have set `visible 
 = { this.state.modalVisible }`.  Also in `Details.js` you have written `<AddModal modalVisible ...`>.

First I changed `showModal` to `modalVisible` in `Details.js` and in `AppModal.js`.

**Details.js**

```
constructor()
{
    super ()
    this.state = {
        data: [],
        modalVisible: false,
        id: null,
    }
}
```

Then I changed `_onPressItem(id)` to `_onPressItem = (id)`

Made changes in `renderItem` as

```
<TouchableHighlight
   id = { item.enName }
   onPress = { () => this._onPressItem(item.enName) }
>
```

in `render` function I have set modal visibility as

```
<AddModal
  ...
  setModalVisible = { (vis) => { this.setState({
     modalVisible: vis
   })
  }}
  ...
/>
```

**AppModal.js**

Changed `showModal` to `modalVisible`

```
constructor(props) {
  super(props);
  this.state = {
    modalVisible: props.modalVisible,
    d: null
  };
}

componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps) {
  this.setState({
    modalVisible: nextProps.modalVisible,
      id: nextProps.id,
  })
}
```

In the constructor, I have added `modalVisible: props.modalVisible`.

Hope this will help!

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/171408/discussion-on-answer-by-prasun-pal-react-native-modal-with-flatlist-items).

Answer (score 0):

I guess item.menu_desc is an id of each item so it must be {item.menu_desc}  not {id}. Change it like below

```
_renderItem = ({item}) => {
        return (
            <TouchableHighlight
                id = { item.menu_desc }
                onPress = { this._onPressItem(item.menu_desc) }
            >
                <View>
                    <Text>{ item.menu_desc }</Text>
                </View>
            </TouchableHighlight>
        )
    };
```

Comment: ahmm yeah sorry about that, but adding that gave me another problem. the modal is not showing properly and even the flatlist is mess up. I'll add the screen shot so you can see, sir.